# How to change titles in a toctree using glob?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, glob, toctree, myst

I use in my sphinx project a toctree with glob option and I want to show different titles than the H1 of my file or the name of the file with using Titlesonly as option of toctree.

Here is a snap of my code :

in the index.md there is README.md files of my project

````
```{toctree}
---
maxdepth: 1
glob:
---
src/*/*
````

I want to show the 'Project Root' for example 'audit' instead of the title of the file 'Projet audit @shared'

Here is a snap of README.md

```
# Projet audit @shared

* Project Root: `audit`
```

Comment: It looks like you use MyST (https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Yes I am using MyST in order to generate Markdown files documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify the document titles using glob. The syntax for [showing custom titles in reST is described in the documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree).

> Entries
>
> Document titles in the [`toctree`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) will be automatically read from the title of the referenced document. If that isn’t what you want, you can specify an explicit title and target using a similar syntax to reST hyperlinks (and Sphinx’s [cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#xref-syntax)). This looks like:
>
> ```
> .. toctree::
>
>     intro
>     All about strings <strings>
>     datatypes
> ```

Comment: Exactly, glob put automatically titles. I used an explicit title and target using a similar syntax as for reST hyperlinks but for Markdown pages. thanks

Comment: how can you do that in markdown instead of rst?